# I want to disable my submit button until all required fields have values.. how can I do that?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Currently I have a form in my visualforce page which contains all types of fields like (Number, text, dropdown and checkbox).
I want to disable my submit button until all required fields are filled.
Currently I'm able to do this only for text fields as I'm using KeyUp() event.
But it's not working for dropdown and checkbox.
What function I need to use, so that it works for all the field types.
Here is my current code

```
var toValidate = $('#inputName, #inputEmail, #inputTel'),
    valid = false;
toValidate.keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).data('valid', true);
    } else {
        $(this).data('valid', false);
    }
    toValidate.each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('valid') == true) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
    });
    if (valid === true) {
        $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);        
    }
});
```

Comment: you can use onchange javascript function for all fields.

Comment: I used it but it seems its not working